# JQuery Ajax goes in error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My ajax function goes in error after I set the dataType to Json.
That's the code:

Ajax script:

```
$('#da').on("change",function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "callAjaxIndex.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    method: 1,
                    id: $('#da').val(),
                },
                success: function() {
                    alert('test');
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        });
```

callAjaxIndex.php

```
<?PHP
require('includes/core.php');
if ( isset($_POST['method']) ) {
    $sql = "SELECT tratte.nome as 'nome_arrivo', tratte.id as 'id_arrivo' FROM tariffe, tratte WHERE id_arrivo = tratte.id AND id_partenza = '".$_POST['id']."'";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    while ( $tariffe = $query->fetch_array() ) {
        $result[] = array(
            'id' => $tariffe['id_arrivo'],
            'nome' => $tariffe['nome_arrivo']
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
}
?>
```

What's wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Could you share your error

Comment: I don't know, where to read the error.
I'm new in ajax. By the way i mean that it run everything inside
error: function() {
      .....
}

Comment: you can check by firefox inspect element then network and what happens actually

Comment: I use chrome and nothing appears in console.. I will download firefox now

Comment: if you share your computer through teamviewer then i can fix it for you

Comment: No thanks, I already downloaded firefox, where can I read the error?

Comment: In mozilla network the process is in 200 state and it's ok.

Comment: @Francesco331 FYI the chrome dev console has a network tab as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
$(document).on('change', '#da', function(){
     $.post("callAjaxIndex.php", {'method': 1, 'id': $(this).val()}, function(data){
var d = $.parseJSON(data); //here is the data parsed as JSON

        //data is that returned from callAjaxIndex.php file
     });
});
```

```html
<?php
    require('includes/core.php');
    if ( isset($_POST['method']) ) {
        $sql = "SELECT tratte.nome as nome_arrivo, tratte.id as id_arrivo FROM tariffe INNER JOIN tratte ON id_arrivo = tratte.id WHERE id_partenza = '".$_POST['id']."'";
        $query = $conn->query($sql);
        while ( $tariffe = $query->fetch_array() ) {
            $result[] = array(
                'id' => $tariffe['id_arrivo'],
                'nome' => $tariffe['nome_arrivo']
            );
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

Comment: and how does this help?

Comment: I need to return a json guys

Comment: I've mentioned in the code for parsing as JSON. please check

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Function.jQuery.parseJSON (jquery-1.12.4.js:9011)
    at Object.success ((index):41)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at done (jquery-1.12.4.js:9840)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.12.4.js:10311)

That's the result.

Comment: it seems the data which is received from server has html code too. If you can check in developer tools under network section, you can find the response data.

Comment: check this https://ibb.co/frr9Hm it is from google chrome developer tools... just in case

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the error by changing your function to this:

```
//other code
error: function(data)
{
    console.log(data.responseText) 
}
//other code
```

This will tell you why it fails, might be something generic but better than 'error'

Also note:

1. this was done from a phone so excuse any mistakes
2. I'd rather this be treated as a comment until I can get to a machine to help more :)